# tcpdump captured packets not readable

Tags: linux, networking, http, tcpdump

I am new to tcpdump, when I use the following command to capture incoming http packet, I cannot recognize anything readable, such as HTTP, GET, etc. I need to check the header and content part. How to display those in a readable format?

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0 -A 'tcp dst port 80'
E.....@.@..C..
...

...PlV.l...K...........
.....fx
```

Comment: You should use instead a Packet Sniffer that can render appropriate (not all) packets into web readable text.  I use Comm View (Tamosoft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to do you probably **don't** want to use the `-A` option. Running tcpdump without it will give you easier to follow lines summarizing what is happening. You also probably don't want the `-s 0` if you just want to follow along visually. So your command would be something like this:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -ni eth0 tcp dst port 80
```

If you really want to dig into the actual contents of the packets and follow entire TCP streams then you **do** want to use the `-s 0` option to capture the entire packets and you also want to use the `-w filename.cap` option to write the captured packets to a binary file instead of to the terminal. Your command would be something like this:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -s 0 -w /tmp/dump.cap -ni eth0 tcp dst port 80
```

Do or wait for the activity you want to capture then press control-C to exit tcpdump. Use some other program such as the excellent and free GUI program **wireshark** to open the capture file and view what you have captured easily and in as much detail as you like. Be warned, though, it may be a little overwhelming at first if you don't have a solid understanding of networking. It looks like you are running Linux and most Linux distributions have wireshark available as a package. There are also free wireshark downloads for Windows and MacOS too. If the computer you're running tcpdump on is a server and you can't run GUI programs on it you can simply copy the capture file you wrote with tcdump to another computer where you can run GUI programs and open it in wireshark there.

Hope this helps.